# How to get an array of all lat/lng pairs between a provided array of lat/lng pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

What would be a good method of getting all lat/lng pairs between this provided array?

Example array of provided latitudes and longitudes:

```
var locs = [{
        lat: -96.7260,
        lng: 44.2599
    },
    {
        lat: -96.7315,
        lng: 44.3334
    },
    {
        lat: -96.8434,
        lng: 44.3321
    },
    {
        lat: -96.8551,
        lng: 44.2525
    }
]

function getLowAndHighValues(locArr) {
    var latLow = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        latHigh = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        lngLow = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        lngHigh = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    var tmpLng, tmpLat;

    for (var i = locArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmpLng = locArr[i].lng;
        tmpLat = locArr[i].lat;

        if (tmpLng < lngLow) lngLow = tmpLng;
        if (tmpLng > lngHigh) lngHigh = tmpLng;
        if (tmpLat < latLow) latLow = tmpLat;
        if (tmpLat > latHigh) latHigh = tmpLat;
    }

    return {
        latLow,
        latHigh,
        lngLow,
        lngHigh
    }
}

var lowHighVals = getLowAndHighValues(locs); // returns {latLow: -96.8551, latHigh: -96.726, lngLow: 44.2525, lngHigh: 44.3334}
```

Ideally I would then pass `lowHighVals` to `getPairValuesBetweenLowAndHigh` with how I want to increment the values:

```
function getPairValuesBetweenLowAndHigh(lowHighVals, inc) {
    var { latLow, latHigh, lngLow, lngHigh } = lowHighVals;
    var pairs = [];
    var tempLoc = { lat: latLow, lng: lngLow }

    // where I am stuck

    return pairs; 
}

getPairValuesBetweenLowAndHigh(lowHighVals, 0.01);
```

`getPairValuesBetweenLowAndHigh(lowHighVals, 0.01)` would return something along the lines of:

```
// where I'm trying to get
[
    { lat: -96.8551, lng: 44.2525 },
    { lat: -96.8451, lng: 44.2625 },
    { lat: -96.8351, lng: 44.2725 },
    ... up to ...
    { lat: -96.7351, lng: 44.3225 },
    { lat: -96.7260, lng: 44.3334 }
]
```

Comment: What defines `Lowest` and `Highest`?

Comment: It is best to show an example of what you have tried so far and where you are having trouble.

Comment: So as you can see that you have a pair of lat/long in your data. So, you need to prioritize first on what basis you want highest and lowest values. You need to get a pair of values, right, iianw. Either it will be that you need lowest lat value pair or lowest long value pair. You can maybe specify that.

Comment: Keep in mind that Longitude 180 === Longitude -180.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var locs = [{
        lat: -96.7260,
        lng: 44.2599
    },
    {
        lat: -96.7315,
        lng: 44.3334
    },
    {
        lat: -96.8434,
        lng: 44.3321
    },
    {
        lat: -96.8551,
        lng: 44.2525
    }
];

var smallestLat = locs[0], smallestLng = locs[0], biggestLat = locs[0], biggestLng = locs[0];

locs.forEach(function(coord){
  if(coord.lat < smallestLat.lat) smallestLat = coord;
  if(coord.lng < smallestLng.lng) smallestLng = coord;
  if(coord.lat > biggestLat.lat) biggestLat = coord;
  if(coord.lng > biggestLng.lng) biggestLng = coord;
});

console.log("smallestLat",smallestLat)
console.log("smallestLng",smallestLng)
console.log("biggestLat",biggestLat)
console.log("biggestLng",biggestLng)

result = {
  highest : {
    lat: biggestLat.lat > biggestLng.lat?biggestLat.lat:biggestLng.lat,
    lng: biggestLat.lng > biggestLng.lng?biggestLat.lng:biggestLng.lng,
  },
  lowest: {
   lat: smallestLat.lat > smallestLng.lat?smallestLat.lat:smallestLng.lat,
    lng: smallestLat.lng > smallestLng.lng?smallestLat.lng:smallestLng.lng,
  }
}

console.log("result", result);
```

Comment: It looks like this is getting the highest and lowest values from the `locs` array. I've already got this figured out. I edited my question to hopefully clear up what I'm looking for.

Comment: Though this is not exactly what you want, but have a look https://jsfiddle.net/kv06rzn8/

Answer (score 0):

Got to this. I'm interested how it can be optimized.

```js
var locs = [{
    lat: 44.2599,
    lng: -96.7260
  },
  {
    lat: 44.3334,
    lng: -96.7315
  },
  {
    lat: 44.3321,
    lng: -96.8434
  },
  {
    lat: 44.2525,
    lng: -96.8551
  }
]

function getLowAndHighValues(locArr) {
  var latLow = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    latHigh = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
    lngLow = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    lngHigh = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

  var tmpLng, tmpLat;

  for (var i = locArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tmpLng = locArr[i].lng;
    tmpLat = locArr[i].lat;

    if (tmpLng < lngLow) lngLow = tmpLng;
    if (tmpLng > lngHigh) lngHigh = tmpLng;
    if (tmpLat < latLow) latLow = tmpLat;
    if (tmpLat > latHigh) latHigh = tmpLat;
  }

  return {
    latLow,
    latHigh,
    lngLow,
    lngHigh
  }
}

function getPairValuesBetweenLowAndHigh(lowHighVals, precision, fixed) {
  var {
    latLow,
    latHigh,
    lngLow,
    lngHigh
  } = lowHighVals;
  var pairs = [],
    tempLoc;
  var latDiff = parseFloat((Math.abs(latLow - latHigh) / precision).toFixed(8));
  var lngDiff = parseFloat((Math.abs(lngLow - lngHigh) / precision).toFixed(8));

  // push pairs to points
  for (var i = latLow; i <= latHigh; i += latDiff) {
    tempLoc = {
      lat: parseFloat(i.toFixed(fixed)),
      lng: lngLow
    }
    pairs.push(tempLoc);
    
    if ((lngLow === lngHigh) && parseFloat(i.toFixed(fixed)) === latHigh) break;
    
    if (parseFloat(i.toFixed(fixed)) === latHigh) {
     i = latLow;
      lngLow += lngDiff
    }
  }

  // remove duplicates
  pairs = pairs.filter((pair, index) => {
    return index === pairs.findIndex(obj => {
      return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(pair);
    });
  });


  return pairs;
}

var lowHighVals = getLowAndHighValues(locs);
var testResponse = getPairValuesBetweenLowAndHigh(lowHighVals, 8, 4);

console.log("Response", testResponse);
```